# unable to use two SKActions in a group at the same time, inside touchesMoved

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, touchesmoved, skaction

I have a little man that I want to move around the screen when I touch the screen, and I also want to animate him whilst he is moving.  The man moves around the screen just fine, however, he does not animate properly when moving. Specifically, he only starts animating when I release my finger from the screen.  This isn't much good as I would like him to animate as I'm dragging my finger over the screen.  I am calling both actions in a group.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The following code is in my SKSPriteNode

```
    -(void)moveAttacker:(UITouch *)touch {
CGPoint position = [touch locationInNode:self];
CGPoint prevLoc = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
float distanceX = (position.x - prevLoc.x);
float distanceY = (position.y - prevLoc.y);
float newPositionX = self.position.x + distanceX *1.5;
float newPositionY = self.position.y + distanceY *1.5;
CGPoint attackerPosition = CGPointMake(newPositionX, newPositionY);
float distanceA = sqrtf(powf(distanceX, 2) + powf(distanceY, 2));
float time = distanceA / PSAttackerSpeed1;
NSArray *textures;

if (distanceY > 0.3) {

    if(self.typeNSW == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_with_ball_1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_jump2"]];
    }
    if(self.typeQLD == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_withBall_1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_jump2"]];
    }
}
if (distanceX > 1){
    if (self.typeNSW == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_turnRight"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_turnRight_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_turnRight_jump2"]];
    }
    if (self.typeQLD == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_turnRight"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_turnRight_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_turnRight_jump2"]];
    }
}
if (distanceX < -1){
    if(self.typeNSW == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_turnLeft"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_turnLeft_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blue_attacker_turnLeft_jump2"]];
    }
    if(self.typeQLD == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_turnLeft"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_turnLeft_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroon_attacker_turnLeft_jump2"]];
    }
}
if (distanceY < -1){
    if (self.typeNSW == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_jump2"]];
    }
    if (self.typeQLD == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_jump2"]];
    }
}
if (distanceY < -1){
    if(self.typeNSW == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_turnLeft"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_turnLeft_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_turnLeft_jump2"]];
    }
    if(self.typeQLD == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_turnLeft"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_turnLeft_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_turnLeft_jump2"]];
    }
}
if (distanceY < -1){
    if (self.typeNSW == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_turnRight"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_turnRight_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"blueAttacker_backwards_withBall_turnRight_jump2"]];
    }
    if (self.typeQLD == YES){
        textures = @[[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_turnRight"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_turnRight_jump1"],
                     [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"maroonAttacker_backwards_turnRight_jump2"]];
    }
}
if(distanceY > 1 || distanceY < - 1 || distanceX > 2 || distanceX < - 2){
    SKAction *moveAttacker = [SKAction moveTo:attackerPosition duration:time];
    SKAction *animateAttacker = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:PSAttackerJumpSpeed1];
    SKAction *group = [SKAction group:@[animateAttacker, moveAttacker]];
    [self runAction:group];
    }
    }
```

And then this is in touchesMoved in my scene

```
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   PSAttackerNode *attacker = (PSAttackerNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"attacker"];

   for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    [attacker moveAttacker:(UITouch*)touch];
    }
    }
```

Comment: Every time touchesMoved fires (which means every frame while moving the finger) you start a new animation action. Each animation will only have time to play back the first frame of its animation, or not even that.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I must of been doing something very wrong.  Thats a great help, much appreciated, and thanks for taking the time to help me out.